# Сибиреязвенный

Tags: словообразование

Сочетание сибирская язва мне, конечно, знакомо. Но вот слово "сибиреязвенный" услышала впервые. Обычно было "вакцина против сибирской язвы". Словари на Яндексе показали, что слово такое есть и давно. Но интересно, такое образование является регулярным (есть подобные слова?) или все-таки образовалось не так, как должно было бы ожидать. Ведь исходное слово "сибирский", а не "Сибирь", и вполне ожидаемо "сибирско-язвенный". А "сибиреязвенные районы" - это правильно?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Довольно регулярное словообразование.

Во-первых, ожидаемо, не *сибирско-язвенный*, а **сибирскоязвенный**, так как "сибирский" зависимое слово к "язве" (ср. *железнодорожный, южноамериканский*).

Во-вторых, при образовании сложных прилагательных от географических местностей, в первой части слова суффикс зачастую отбрасывается (ср. *Киево-Печерская лавра, Владимиро-Суздальское княжество, итало-немецкие войска, северокорейский режим*).

Не знаю, как вам, мне слово *сибиреязвенный* кажется удобней для употребления, чем *сибирскоязвенный*, видимо поэтому оно и прижилось.

Comment: Спасибо. А как насчет сибиреязвенных районов? Как Вам кажется? Насчет правописания Вы правы. Это я по влиянием географических терминов. Но,  кстати, это современная тенденция: если первая часть заканчивается на  -ско - писать через дефис. Может, когда  и закрепится. Вообще это правило в процессе становления и с большим количеством не подчиняющихся правилу сочетаний.

Comment: Не вижу причин, для не употребления этого словосочетания. У Роберта Шекли есть рассказ "Чумной район", были *тифозные бараки* и т. п.

Comment: Сибирская язва - сочетание географического определения с существительным. Причем здесь Киево- Печерская лавра и Владимиро-Суздальское княжество?? Приведите примеры из серии "географическое" прилагательное + существительное = новое прилагательное... По-вашему, Марк Из, "это довольно регулярное образование". Ждем многочисленных примеров!

Comment: :-) У Ильфа и Петрова в "12 стульях" есть диковатое сочетание Военно-Грузинская дорога.

Comment: @Nikolja, не только у Ильфа и Петрова. Военно-Грузинская дорога - это дорога, через Главный Каказский хребет, соединяющая Владикавказ и Тбилиси. Дорога функционирует с XVIII века. Чрездефисное написание здесь обусловлено тем, что дорога не военной Грузии, а военная (строилась прежде всего для переброски войск) и грузинская (из России в Грузию).

Comment: Сибиреязвенный  район  ещё  нормальное  словосочетание,  а  вот  сибиреязвенная  вакцина  как-то  не  очень.

Answer (score 9):

Слово сибирско-язвенный достаточно двусмысленное, на мой взгляд. Непонятно, к чему относится первая часть слова *сибирско-* : к Сибири как месту события? к особой форме язвенной инфекции? *Сибиреязвенный* вариант не оставляет сомнений в значении медицинского термина.
Такие словообразования очень редко встречаются. Могу предложить следующие окказионализмы :
*кремлестенный

берлинолазурный

москвостильный

валдаефорумный

китаесиндромный

мароккоапельсиновый

чилипутчевый

таемассажный

египтопирамидный*
...

Нашел в литературе нечастый пример подобных сложных прилагательных :

> Булгаков — это Москва 30-х годов, довоенная, **москвошвейная**. Это мир родных арбатских переулков, это дом в Нащокинском...
>   [Михаил Булгаков в Художественном театре - А. Смелянский | belousenko.com](http://www.belousenko.com/books/litera/smelyansky_mxat.htm)

Московская швея - "Москвошвея" - **москвошвейная**.

> "Пивная. Ещё парочку.
>   МОСКВОШВЕЯ, МОСКВОШВЕЯ.
>   Пивная. Ещё парочку.
>   Буржуи, буржуи.
>   Не толкайся, подлец, слезай с подножки.
>   Я тебе покажу, твою мать!"
>   Булгаков, "Собачье сердце"

Автору вопроса я твердо отвечаю : есть **подобные** слова!

Предлагаю на его суд новое прилагательное **черноморокруизный** : *незабываемые черноморокруизные впечатления* (исходное словосочетание - черноморский круиз).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Исправьте свою ошибку, Ларf. Ответ Марк Из'а неверный, Вам ли этого не видеть.

Comment: Спасибо за слово москвошвейная.

Comment: Очень редкие слова с данной конструкцией, в большинстве своем - окказионализмы или профессиональный жаргон.

Comment: Да, Вы правы , сибиреязвенная - профессионализм. Поэтому, наверное, и показалось мне необычным.

Answer (score 9):

Хотя слово «сибиреязвенный» выглядит необычно, оно вполне вписывается в систему словообразования, представленную «Грамматикой-80».Способ образования – чистое сложение двух основ (сибир-е-язвенный). Характер основ подчинительный: первый компонент уточняет значение второго, в качестве первого компонента используется усеченная основа прилагательного сибирский. Для сравнения: сейсмоактивный (сейсмический), взаимоприемлемый (взаимный), обоюдовыгодный (обоюдный), также северокорейский (северный), но: южнокорейский. Таким образом, слово ищет для себя удобную фонетическую форму в тех рамках, которые ей предоставляются словообразовательной системой.

Comment: Спасибо, София, за четкий ответ.